# Question about segment of code in XNA

Tags: xna-4.0, monogame

Basically when the code says

```
public static Camera Instance
{
// Code and something with get statement
}
```

Is it declaring a method? I don't think it is a method because there is no parenthesis to indicate the area to put in parameters.
Here is the full class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;

namespace ScrollingTest
{
    public class Camera
    {
    private static Camera instance;
    public static Camera Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
                instance = new Camera();
            return instance;

        }

    }
}
}
```

Comment: This is solely a C# question by the way, not a game development question.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static Camera Instance
{
    get
    {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new Camera();
        return instance;

    }
}
```

This is called a [Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx).

Comment: And it is static because there is only one camera and it needs to be accessible everywhere. The purpose of this property is to allow read-only access to the private instance. Camera can modify instance, but everyone else can only retrieve it. They have also allowed Camera to initialize the static instance, if/when something first requests it. If the Camera constructor is made private, then Cameras (only one) can only be created through this property.

Comment: And, by adding a set{}, the property becomes read/write.